# During converting json string into bean object gson().fromJson() method throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY”

Tags: java, json, gson, getjson

I am trying to convert a json string into bean object as follow -

```
 PinsRequestTo objPinsRequestTo = new PinsRequestTo();
 objPinsRequestTo = new Gson().fromJson(pinMessageJson, PinsRequestTo.class);
```

My Bean object is as follow

```
 public class PinsRequestTo {
   private String message;
   private JsonArray keypattern_id_list;

   public String getMessage() {
       return message;
   }

   public void setMessage(String message) {
       this.message = message;
   }

   public JsonArray getKeypattern_id_list() {
       return keypattern_id_list;
   }

   public void setKeypattern_id_list(JsonArray keypattern_id_list) {
       this.keypattern_id_list = keypattern_id_list;
   }
}
```

And the json string is as follow

```
{
 "keypattern_id_list":["C0000011MSZPIN2015010760417236","C0000011MSZPIN2015010760294357"]
}
```

I am getting exception during this process which is as follow

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 25
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
......
......
```

I want to set the property keypattern_id_list of PinsRequestTo with the array in json string. What should I do. If there is any other approach then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're sure that your source JSON isn't surrounded by `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Change `keypattern_id_list` variable type from `JsonArray` to `List<String>` in your **PinsRequestTo** class then it should look something like this:

```
public class PinsRequestTo {
    private String message;
    private List<String> keypattern_id_list;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<String> getKeypattern_id_list() {
        return keypattern_id_list;
    }

    public void setKeypattern_id_list(List<String> keypattern_id_list) {
        this.keypattern_id_list = keypattern_id_list;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("PinsRequestTo [message=").append(message)
                .append(", keypattern_id_list=").append(keypattern_id_list)
                .append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

and the deserialization logic is as follows:

```
String pinMessageJson = "{\"keypattern_id_list\":[\"C0000011MSZPIN2015010760417236\",\"C0000011MSZPIN2015010760294357\"]}";

PinsRequestTo objPinsRequestTo = new Gson().fromJson(pinMessageJson, PinsRequestTo.class);
System.out.println(objPinsRequestTo);
```

and this is the output of the print statement:

```
PinsRequestTo [message=null, keypattern_id_list=[C0000011MSZPIN2015010760417236, C0000011MSZPIN2015010760294357]]
```

maven dependency for gson is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```